# How to see DynamoDB table name in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, amazon-dynamodb

I can't see the name of the tables already created. I'm working on a project in which I have access to the DynamoDB database through an IAM client, I create the AmazonClient using the credentials and configs that were made available to me, but I can't see the tables already created in the database.

I have already created the client and connected it to the database, I am trying to see the number of tables as follows, but the result is always 0

[new code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Jo2D.png)

```
List<string> currentTables = client.ListTablesAsync().Result.TableNames;
MessageBox.Show(currentTables.Count.ToString());
```

Comment: I'm not a C# person, but you are using the Async Client, are you awaiting the results before completing?

Answer (score 0):

Try awaiting the API call:

```
List<string> currentTables = await client.ListTablesAsync().Result.TableNames;
            MessageBox.Show(currentTables.Count.ToString());
```

Try this sync code instead:

```
AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();

// Initial value for the first page of table names.
string lastEvaluatedTableName = null;
do
{
   // Create a request object to specify optional parameters.
   var request = new ListTablesRequest
   {
     Limit = 10, // Page size.
     ExclusiveStartTableName = lastEvaluatedTableName
   };

   var response = client.ListTables(request);
   ListTablesResult result = response.ListTablesResult;
   foreach (string name in result.TableNames)
     Console.WriteLine(name);

   lastEvaluatedTableName = result.LastEvaluatedTableName;

} while (lastEvaluatedTableName != null);
```

Comment: I don't speak Portuguese sorry

Comment: Sorry, I had a translated site, I forgot to write in English, but I meant that I don't have access to the synchronous functions, only the asynchronous ones, I tried to put the await before and change the method that uses the function to async, but it keeps giving 0.